# NSSound related crashes on Sonoma

Tags: objective-c, appkit, nssound

We've been doing the following in our app for years without issues:

`[[NSSound soundNamed:@"Basso"] play]`

Suddenly we're seeing hundreds of crashes from macOS 14.0 users and we're not sure what's causing this. There are no memory leaks within the app and all the stack traces are around `NSSound`:

```
0  AudioToolbox                   0x1f558 MEDeviceStreamClient::RemoveRunningClient(AQIONodeClient&, bool, bool) + 3096
1  AudioToolbox                   0x1e8fc AQMEDevice::RemoveRunningClient(AQIONodeClient&, bool) + 108
2  AudioToolbox                   0x1e854 AQMixEngine_Base::RemoveRunningClient(AQIONodeClient&, bool) + 76
3  AudioToolbox                   0xcdd78 AudioQueueObject::StopRunning(AQIONode*, bool) + 244
4  AudioToolbox                   0xcbdd0 AudioQueueObject::Stop(bool, bool, int*) + 736
5  AudioToolbox                   0xf1840 AudioQueueXPC_Server::Stop(unsigned int, bool) + 172
6  AudioToolbox                   0x1418b4 ___ZN20AudioQueueXPC_Bridge4StopEjb_block_invoke + 72
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x3910 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x130f8 _dispatch_sync_invoke_and_complete_recurse + 64
9  AudioToolbox                   0x141844 AudioQueueXPC_Bridge::Stop(unsigned int, bool) + 184
10 AudioToolbox                   0xa09b0 AQ::API::V2Impl::AudioQueueStop(OpaqueAudioQueue*, unsigned char) + 492
11 AVFAudio                       0xbe12c AVAudioPlayerCpp::disposeQueue(bool) + 188
12 AVFAudio                       0x341dc -[AudioPlayerImpl dealloc] + 72
13 AVFAudio                       0x358a0 -[AVAudioPlayer dealloc] + 36
14 AppKit                         0x1b13b4 -[NSAVAudioPlayerSoundEngine dealloc] + 44
15 AppKit                         0x1b132c -[NSSound dealloc] + 164
16 libobjc.A.dylib                0xf418 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 196
17 libobjc.A.dylib                0xbaf0 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 260
18 CoreFoundation                 0x3c57c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 32
19 Foundation                     0x30e88 -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 140
20 Foundation                     0x31f94 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 92
21 AE                             0xbd8c _AppleEventsCheckInAppWithBlock + 13808
22 AE                             0xb6b4 _AppleEventsCheckInAppWithBlock + 12056
23 AE                             0x4cc4 aeProcessAppleEvent + 488
24 HIToolbox                      0x402d4 AEProcessAppleEvent + 68
25 AppKit                         0x3a29c _DPSNextEvent + 1440
26 AppKit                         0x80db94 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 716
27 AppKit                         0x2d43c -[NSApplication run] + 476
28 AppKit                         0x4708 NSApplicationMain + 880
29 ???                            0x180739058 (Missing)
```

Comment: So odd - it was always `soundNamed` not sure why I typed `systemSound` !